# How to generate .tf/.tflite files from python

Tags: tensorflow

I am trying to generate the custom tensor flow model (tf/tflite file) which i wanted to use for my mobile application.

I have gone through few machine learning and tensor flow blogs, from there I started to generate a simple ML model.

1. https://www.datacamp.com/community/tutorials/tensorflow-tutorial
2. https://www.edureka.co/blog/tensorflow-object-detection-tutorial/
3. https://blog.metaflow.fr/tensorflow-how-to-freeze-a-model-and-serve-it-with-a-python-api-d4f3596b3adc
4. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ICY4Lvhyobk

All these are really nice and they guided me to do the below steps,

i)Install all necessary tools (TensorFlow,Python,Jupyter,etc).
ii)Load the Training and testing Data.
iii)Run the tensor flow session for train and evaluate the results.
iv)Steps to increase the accuracy

But i am not able to generate the .tf/.tflite files.

I tried the following code, but that generates an empty file.

```
converter = tf.contrib.lite.TFLiteConverter.from_session(sess,[],[]) 
model = converter.convert()

file = open( 'model.tflite' , 'wb' ) 
file.write( model )
```

I have checked few answers in stackoverflow and according to my understanding in-order to generate the .tf files we need to create the pb files, freezing the pb file and then generating the .tf files.

But how can we achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Tensorflow provides Tflite converter to convert saved model to Tflite model.For more details find [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/convert).

```
tf.lite.TFLiteConverter.from_saved_model() (recommended): Converts a SavedModel.

tf.lite.TFLiteConverter.from_keras_model(): Converts a Keras model.

tf.lite.TFLiteConverter.from_concrete_functions(): Converts concrete functions.
```